# Best Java Object for Incredibly Small Decimals

Tags: java, data-structures, decimal

What java object is best suited to hold tiny decimal values, such as 10^-25? What object will maintain the value of the number most accurately, while using the least space?

I simply need to store the value for display, not use it for any calculations. Are there other alternatives I could use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store it as a String. There's no need to use numerical data types if you aren't doing calculations.

Comment: That was intentional. I'm happy to be wrong, but I believe the JRE is going to convert any numerical data type to a String for output anyway. Starting with a String bypasses that conversion and uses less memory.

Comment: There was a comment about ignoring the size of a String object, which now seems to be missing.

Comment: @yock: I removed the comment when I acknowledged that BigDecimal has high overhead and was actually likely to occupy more memory on average for common values.  However, regarding your comment, the String that would be created to display the value isn't the memory concern; it is transient, not resident.  Temporary memory is usually not the worry, but rather the longer term requirements.  For arbitrary decimal values BigDecimal will occupy less memory.

Comment: The other main deficiency of using a String is that because it hasn't been parsed, you can change formats (e.g. for localization or preferences).  That may or may not be an issue for the OP.

Comment: It would probably be helpful then to know the nature of the OP's memory limitation.

Comment: @Mark: If you look at BigDecimal it may at times have a String object reference internally (transient but as a representation cache assigned upon first use of `toString()`), it keeps a BigInteger reference which itself has a char[] reference and several additional ints. It would take a lot of numeric digits for a String storage to exceed BigDecimal storage for the same value.

Answer (score 4):

`BigDecimal` will do just fine.

```
BigDecimal dec = BigDecimal.valueOf(1, -25);
```

The main reason to prefer this over a String is because you can change/customize your format.  If you keep it as a String, it will be stuck in whatever format it originally had until you parse it, meaning you can't do localization, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you truly don't need to do *any* calculations with these values, a `String` would be hacky but sufficient. Alternately, you could use the arbitrary-precision [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use double and if not enough, you also have the [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class. However, if you are not computing anything, I would simply store them as strings in the way I receive them.

Answer (score 1):

There's always a tradeoff of space vs. precision when dealing with decimal numbers. Floats (and doubles) have less accuracy in the extreme ends of their ranges, but are more space efficient than, say, BigDecimal. And they can generate infinite series when representing certain numbers (like 0.1).

Go with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal will be perfectly accurate but use (comparatively) a lot of space. Just a plain old primitive double will give you 15 digits of precision, so unless you need absolutely exact values (as in financial calculations), I'd say double is your best bet

Comment: BigDecimal will use more or less "as much space as you need to use" for the desired precision. I don't think there's a practical alternative that uses so much less space to be worth bothering with.

Comment: @Neil: it's hard to beat a double unless you truly need more than those 15 digits. A double is 8 bytes. Sun's BigDecimal implementation includes two int members and two object references; conservatively, that's 16 bytes right there. One of those object references always points to a BigInteger value, which contains five ints and an int[] reference, for another 24 bytes.

Comment: The int[] will contain an indeterminate number of ints; plus there's the object overhead which used to be 16 bytes per object although it's probably smaller these days; let's make it 4 bytes to be super optimistic. That means the smallest possible BigDecimal contains 52 bytes, and realistically most will be a lot larger than that.

Comment: Remember that a double stores so many BINARY digits precisely, whereas a BigDecimal stores an arbitrary number of DECIMAL digits precisely. Even within a given range of precision, they're not quite the same thing. I'm also going to stick my neck out and say that in a typical application, you can usually afford an extra 20-50 bytes or so to store a number.

Comment: *A* number, sure. If it's an array of 100,000, then it makes a big difference. He mentioned space, so that's why I mentioned it. And you're absolutely right that double can't store the exact value of many very common non-repeating decimal numbers.

Comment: Maaaaaaaybe, but even 100K numbers at 50 bytes/number is only about 5 megabytes. I take your point that space was mentioned, I would just say that it's probably only under fairly extreme circumstances that you'll need to worry about the storage space of a BigDecimal vs double.